# how to fix append() error after passing a list

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to append the list to itself but it says "takes exactly one argument"
I have tried using other variables to store the splited line.

```
 testfile = open(r'''C:\Users\shawa\Desktop\sampleg102.txt''' ,'r')
 print(testfile) 

 word=list
 for line in testfile:
     line = line.lstrip()
     word = word.append([1])
 print(word)
```

and the error is

```
E:\vscode.source> python -u "e:\vscode.source\python\countingWords.py"
 <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\shawa\\Desktop\\sampleg102.txt' 
mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "e:\vscode.source\python\countingWords.py", line 7, in <module>
    word = word.append([1])
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Comment: `word=list()`....and replace `word = word.append([1])` to just `word.append([1])`

Comment: `word=list()` or `word = []` should instantiate your list properly, also you can just append `1` ti the list via `word.append(1)`

Answer (score 0):

To explain the first mistake, take a look at this:

```
>>> list
<class 'list'>
>>> word = list
>>> word
<class 'list'>
>>> word = list()
>>> word
<list object at 0x...>
```

At the moment, you have only assigned the name `list` to the name `word`. You need to call the `list` constructor to actually create the list. Now, the method `list.append()` modifies the list in-place. It returns `None` and you don’t need to re-assign it.

```
word = list()
# word = '' works too
for line in testfile:
    line = line.lstrip()
    word.append([1])
print(word)
```

Your code will print a list of lists of 1s at the moment. If you meant to append the lines of the file, use

```
word.append(line)
```

*Note that it’s preferable to use the literal `[]` empty list syntax rather than calling `list()` as it makes it very clear what is being created.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this if you are trying to append line to list. In your code you are appending only [1] to the list word.

```
testfile = open(r'''C:\Users\shawa\Desktop\sampleg102.txt''' ,'r')
print(testfile) 

 word=list()
 for line in testfile:
     line = line.lstrip()
     word.append(1) #or word.append(line[1]) according to use case
 print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for word=list() not word=list. list is just a keyword, list() instantiates